# How to modify the below code to copy the value from the next adjacent cell and paste it in Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am a new learner of Excel VBA. Please help to modify the below Code to copy the value from next adjacent cell as this code copies the value from the same Column and cells

```
Public Sub FindSales()

    Dim sValToFind As String
    Dim rSearchRange As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rFoundCell As Range
    Dim rAllFoundCells As Range
    Dim sMessage As String

    sValToFind = InputBox("Please enter Sales Order No.")
    'Code to check a valid number entered
    '.
    '.

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With rSearchRange
        Set rFoundCell = .Find(sValToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAdd = rFoundCell.Address
            Do

                sMessage = sMessage & rFoundCell.Row & ", "

                'Create a range of found cells.
                If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, rFoundCell)
                Else
                    Set rAllFoundCells = rFoundCell
                End If
                Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)
            Loop While rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAdd
        End If
    End With

    rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    sMessage = sValToFind & " found on rows " & Mid(sMessage, 1, Len(sMessage) - 2) & "."
    MsgBox sMessage, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here are a couple of functions you can use to determine which column a specific header is in.  Once you have the column and row, you can use that to set your destination range.

```
Function Find_Column_Heading(ByRef shTarget As Worksheet, ByVal myHeading As String) As Long
'search row 1 of shTarget for a specific heading and return the column number
Dim intMaxCol As Long, intColCount As Long, varFindCell As Variant, rngToLookIn As Range
intMaxCol = shTarget.Cells(1, shTarget.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rngToLookIn = shTarget.Range(shTarget.Cells(1, 1), shTarget.Cells(1, intMaxCol))
Set varFindCell = rngToLookIn.find(what:=myHeading, after:=shTarget.Cells(1, 1), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not varFindCell Is Nothing Then
    Find_Column_Heading = varFindCell.Column
Else
    Find_Column_Heading = intMaxCol + 1
End If
End Function


Function Find_Bottom_Row(ByRef shTarget As Worksheet, intColumn As Long) As Long
'this will return the row of the empty cell below the lowest used cell in the specified column
Find_Bottom_Row = shTarget.Cells(shTarget.Rows.Count, intColumn).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End Function



Dim rFoundCell As Range, NextFoundCell As Range 'Add a new variable


Set NextFoundCell = rFoundCell.Offset(0, 1) 'this selects the cell to the right of the search target

'Create a range of found cells.
If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, NextFoundCell) 'add the cell to the right to the result range
Else
    Set rAllFoundCells = NextFoundCell
End If
```

Comment: Please help to modify the above code to find the value matching the Columns heading in the sheet 2 and paste the found values underneath each column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you need the destination to vary according to the column heading?  So in "rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")" the destination range should be variable?

Comment: I want to work through the Column Headers (e.g. Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") and search the values in the corresponding columns of Sheet1. The current code works fine however it runs only for the first column in Sheet 2 and i need the code to work for all the columns in sheet 2 and paste the found values under each respective columns. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Search destination in sheet 1 is same however there are different values to be searched in each column in sheet 2 as per the values in column heading and found values to be pasted under each column of the searched value respectively

Comment: OK, so you'll have to add a loop to work through all of the used columns in sheet 2, so range ("A1") will change to B1, C1, etc.  While most will insist that ranges are better, you can use cells (1,1) instead, so you can count from 1 to maxcolumns and use sheet2.cells(1,columnnumber) for each step in the loop.  You'll probably need to restructure your whole procedure a bit.  Do a Main, that goes through the column headings, and calls sub Onecolumn that finds the value for that column, and so one.  Easier to structure that way.

Comment: I tried the below code as advised however its still running for the first column and then its shows the run time error.. Unable to figure out whats wrong..

Comment: i have posted the code as an answer above.. please do check and let me know

Comment: i ran the code step by step by F8 and found that The above Code runs successfully for 1st column and the result is displayed and then the run time error occurs for the second column in this line "rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, columnNo)"

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub FindVa()

Dim sValToFind As String
Dim rSearchRange As Range
Dim sFirstAdd As String
Dim rFoundCell As Range, NextFoundCell As Range
Dim rAllFoundCells As Range
Dim sMessage As String


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
my_row = Selection.Column



For i = 1 To my_row



sValToFind = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

With rSearchRange
     Set rFoundCell = .Find(sValToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
     If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAdd = rFoundCell.Address
        Do

            sMessage = sMessage & rFoundCell.Row & ", "
            Set NextFoundCell = rFoundCell.Offset(0, 1)

            If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, NextFoundCell)
            Else
                Set rAllFoundCells = NextFoundCell
            End If
            Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)
        Loop While rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAdd
     End If
End With

rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, i)
Set rSearchRange = Null
Set rFoundCell = Null
Set NextFoundCell = Null
Set rAllFoundCells = Null



'sMessage = sValToFind & " found on rows " & Mid(sMessage, 1, Len(sMessage) - 2) & "."
'MsgBox sMessage, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
'sMessage = ""

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: adding an explaination to your answer would help